# Duplicating discrete x-axis for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi this is similar to another post however what I wanted to do here is duplicate x-axis for top and bottom and not just move it to the top. I tried using  `scale_x_discrete(sec.axis = dup_axis())` but that did not work. Below is my working example

```
d<- data.frame (pid=c("d","b","c"), type=c("rna","rna","rna"), value = c(1,2,3) )
d2 <- data.frame (pid=c("d","b","c"), type=c("dna","dna","dna"), value = c(10,20,30) )
df <- rbind (d,d2)

ggplot(df, aes(y=pid, x=type  ) ) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") 
  # this failed: scale_x_discrete(sec.axis = dup_axis())
```

The plot currently looks like this but I want x to show up top and bottom. 
[image]

Comment: If you have found similar questions, can you provide links and also explain what didn't work with them?

Comment: a similar post is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838005/putting-x-axis-at-top-of-ggplot2-chart however this was only to move the axis to the top and duplication is for continous

Comment: I just found a solution by converting to numeric and then relabeling but I'm wondering if there is another ggplot option. 
```df$type <- as.numeric ( df$type )
ggplot(df, aes(y=pid, x=type  ) ) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2), labels = c("Start", "n-1"), sec.axis = dup_axis() ) ```

Comment: This should be added to the question, not the comments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `scale_x_discrete` function does not have a second axes argument, but `scale_x_continuous` does. So editing the `type` variable to a numeric variable and then changing the label would work:

```
d<- data.frame (pid=c("d","b","c"), type=1, value = c(1,2,3) )
d2 <- data.frame (pid=c("d","b","c"), type= 2, value = c(10,20,30) )
df <- rbind (d,d2)

ggplot(df, aes(y=pid, x=type)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2,
                      labels = c("rna", "dna"),
                      sec.axis = dup_axis())
```

[image]